# How to create simple database with only 2 columns and use it in Android? (using SQLiteOpenHelper)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Well, I've got some code below, but I don't really know how it works and how to fill it.  I need to fill it with about 30 thousands elements.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 static final String dbName="demoDB";

 static final String quoteTable="Quote";
 static final String quoteID="ID";
 static final String quoteText="Quote";

 static final String viewEmps="ViewEmps";


 public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, dbName, null,33);
      }




public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+quoteTable+" ("+
    quoteID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "+
            quoteText+ " TEXT)");

}
```

Comment: You need someone to provide a working solution for you? Then Stackoverflow is not a right place for such questions.

Comment: No i just wanted to get some useful links. Like Ria gave.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this three useful tutorials:

- [on vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
- [on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android)
- [on androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)